# Search two perl regex and store in one declared variable

Tags: regex, perl, variables

So this is the scenario:

1. I perform a perl regex search on a string and store it in a variable
2. I then want to retrieve a substring from that variable and save it under the same variable

When I try with two separate variables it works, but I would like to minimies my variable declaration. What currently works:

```
my ($temp1)         = ($buildLog =~ /(build\_version.*\d*)/);
my ($buildVersion)  = ($temp1 =~ /(\d.*)/);

print "$temp1\n"; #$temp1 contains: build_version = 1411450178

print "$buildVersion\n"; #$buildVersion contains: 1411450178
```

But when I try to do it with one variable it only prints out the 1 ie that it found the match, but I would like the actual value. See below:

```
my ($temp2)     = ($buildLog =~ /(build\_version.*\d*)/);
$temp2          = ($temp2 =~ /(\d.*)/);

print "$temp2\n"; #$temp1 just prints out 1
```

Could anybody please provide a quick explination of the behaviour and if it is indeed possible to use only one variable to get the content of the search ?

Thanks,
CJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one regex is needed:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $buildLog = 'foobar build_version = 1411450178 bazbiz';

my ($buildVersion) = $buildLog =~ /build_version\D*(\d+)/;

print "$buildVersion\n";
```

Outputs:

```
1411450178
```

Comment: Thank you! I completley overlooked the fact that you can use the parenthesese that way. :D

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26006233/2676699) has the correct solution for what you are trying to do.  I just wanted to provide a quick explanation of why your code is not working as you expect.

You are confusing scalar and list modes.  Your code

```
$temp2          = ($temp2 =~ /(\d.*)/);
```

is taking the results of the match (in a list context) and assigning it to a scalar.  This assigns the number of elements in the list to the scalar.

You could also have used

```
$temp2          = ($temp2 =~ /(\d.*)/)[0];
```

to pick up the first match result.

@jm666's answer works because it assigns the list of match results to a list of variables.

Comment: thanks a lot :D this helps a lot in my understanding of how it works :D

Answer (score 0):

The following

```
my ($temp2)     = ($buildLog =~ /(build\_version.*\d*)/);
($temp2)        = ($temp2 =~ /(\d.*)/);
```

will print

```
 1411450178
```